# Prescriptive advice on minimally invasive conversion from Remoting to WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, remoting

Is the advice given in this oft-cited [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857(VS.80).aspx) still considered sound for converting a .NET Remoting application to WCF?

I notice that the article references the deprecated ServiceBehavior attribute ReturnUnknownExceptionsAsFaults, so I question whether people have found other discrepancies or other approaches better suited to introducing WCF into an existing application in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that [Integration with .NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730332.aspx) links back to it ("[From .NET Remoting to the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857%28VS.80%29.aspx)"), I guess the answer has to be "yes".

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to get a sanity check before I went down the rabbit hole.